# Performance issue in coredata in swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm saving the information I get from the JSON API to Coredata. There are, however, some performance concerns. When I first log in to the app, I delete the data from my coredata and save the json fetching data to coredata.As a result of receiving a huge volume of data from the server, I am experiencing performance issues.  Now I'm going to add my code. Could you please tell me where the code is going wrong for me? Is it a good idea to do all CRUD operations on their own thread? How can I utilize performBackgroundTask for these CRUD operations?

**All my CRUD operations are:**

```
class EmployeeDataStore {
     enum EmployeeDataStoreError: Error {
        case couldNotCastToType
    }
    
    static let shared: EmployeeDataStore = {
        let instance = EmployeeDataStore()
        return instance
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        guard let modelURL = Bundle(for: EmployeeDataStore.self).url(forResource: "JsonEmployeeDataStore", withExtension: "momd")
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to find XCDataModeld File")
        }
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed initializing the momd file: \(modelURL)")
        }

        let coord = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = coord

        guard let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to find document url.")
        }
        // Odd issue where simulator doesn't have documents folder
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentURL.absoluteString) {
            try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: documentURL,
                                                     withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                     attributes: nil)
        }

        let storeURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("JsonEmployeeDataStore.sqlite")

        do {
            let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                           NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
            try coord.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                         configurationName: nil,
                                         at: storeURL,
                                         options: options)
        } catch {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to get database.")
        }

        return moc
    }()

    func saveIfNeeded() throws {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        }
    }

    func create<T: NSManagedObject>() throws -> T {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
        guard let objects = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "\(T.self)",
                                                                into: managedObjectContext) as? T else {
            throw EmployeeDataStoreError.couldNotCastToType
        }
        return objects
    }

    func getAll<T: NSManagedObject>(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [T] {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "\(T.self)")
        fetch.predicate = predicate
        guard let objects = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetch) as? [T] else {
            throw EmployeeDataStoreError.couldNotCastToType
        }
        return objects
    }

    func removeAll<T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "\(type)")
        fetch.predicate = predicate
        let delete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetch)
        try managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.execute(delete, with: managedObjectContext)
    }
}
```

**Functions in my view controller when I am executing CRUD operations:**

```
 protocol getDataProtocol {
    func update(key: String, data: Data, uid: String) throws
    func getStoreValues(key: String, userid: String) throws -> [StoreManagedObjectValue]
}

 struct StoreDataAccess: getDataProtocol {
    private let dataAccess = AccessCoreData<StoreManagedObjectValue>()
    
    public init() {
        // this function is required to allow public level initialization of the StoreDataAccess struct
    }

public func update(key: String, data: Data, uid: String) throws {
    try removeStoreValues(key: key, uid: uid)

    let newData = try dataAccess.create()
    newData.key = key
    newData.data = data
    newData.uid = uid

    try dataAccess.save()
}

public func getStoreValues(key: String, userid: String) throws -> [StoreValue] {
    let key = key
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@ AND userid == %@", NSNumber(value: key), userid)
    return try dataAccess.getAll(predicate: pred)
}

public func getAllStoreValues() throws -> [StoreManagedObjectValue] {
    try dataAccess.getAll()
}

    public func removeStoreValues(key: String, uid: String) throws {
        let key = key
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@ AND uid == %@", NSNumber(value: key), userid)
        try dataAccess.removeAll(predicate: pred)
        
        try dataAccess.save()
    }
    
}
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
struct AccessCoreData<T: NSManagedObject> {
    func create() throws -> T {
        try EmployeeDataStore.shared.create()
    }

    func getAll(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [T] {
        try EmployeeDataStore.shared.getAll(predicate: predicate)
    }

    func removeAll(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws {
        try EmployeeDataStore.shared.removeAll(type: T.self, predicate: predicate)
    }

    func save() throws {
        try EmployeeDataStore.shared.saveIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty open-ended, and I don't think you can get many useful responses unless you colour in some more detail. Have you profiled this? What are the hot-spots?